# Azure Pipeline Does not execute conditional logic correctly

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I want to add conditional logic to only run a step if a certain repository has been included (this is a generic yaml script).

To achieve this, I have added a variable:

```
variables:
  templateRepositoryRef: $[ resources.repositories['templates'].ref ]
```

And added the following check:

```
steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['templateRepositoryRef'], 'refs') }}:
    - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef contains refs
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
- ${{ else }}:
     - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef does not contain refs
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
```

The idea being that if the repository resource with the alias `templates` is contained, this will be a non-empty string.

The output of this is:

```
templateRepositoryRef does not contain refs
templateRepositoryRef: refs/heads/feature/jira-1234
Finishing: CmdLine
```

In what world does this make sense? Why is the condition behaving the opposite of how I would expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this issue and do not know why the if/else expressions aren't behaving as expected.

As a workaround I was able to use step conditions to get the desired behavior:

```
variables:
  templateRepositoryRef: $[ resources.repositories['templates'].ref ]
  ContainsRefs: $[contains(resources.repositories['templates'].ref, 'refs')]

steps:
- script: |
    echo templateRepositoryRef contains refs
    echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
    echo ContainsRefs: $(ContainsRefs)
  condition: eq(variables['ContainsRefs'],True)

- script: |
    echo templateRepositoryRef does not contain refs
    echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
    echo ContainsRefs: $(ContainsRefs)
  condition: eq(variables['ContainsRefs'],False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can also reproduce the issue. In [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines#variables), it also introduces the repository resource variables.  Then I try to find the reason why it doesn't work as expected.

When I noticed what was in the Job preparation parameters, I ran the following test.
[image]

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      ref: main
      name: one

variables:
  templateRepositoryRef:  $[ resources.repositories.templates.ref ]

steps:

- ${{ if contains(variables['templateRepositoryRef'], 'refs') }}:
    - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef contains refs
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
- ${{ else }}:
     - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef does not contain refs
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)

- ${{ if contains(variables['templateRepositoryRef'], 'ref') }}:
    - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef contains ref
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)
- ${{ else }}:
     - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef does not contain ref
        echo templateRepositoryRef: $(templateRepositoryRef)

- ${{ if contains(variables['templateRepositoryRef'], 'resources.repositories.templates.ref') }}:
    - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef contains resources.repositories.templates.ref
- ${{ else }}:
     - script: |
        echo templateRepositoryRef does not contain resources.repositories.templates.ref
```

result:

```
templateRepositoryRef does not contain refs
templateRepositoryRef contains ref
templateRepositoryRef contains resources.repositories.templates.ref
templateRepositoryRef: refs/heads/main
```

So for this question

> Why is the condition behaving the opposite of how I would expect it to.

The answer is that when using the expression in  `- ${{ if contains(variables['templateRepositoryRef'], 'refs') }}:`, the value of it is still `resources.repositories.templates.ref`.  When you `echo` it in the task, it will be `refs/heads/xxxx`. However, I am not sure if this is a bug or designed.

And you can use Tod Mahoy's workaround to get the desired behavior.